# Не запускается программа по подсчету вероятности

Tags: python, python-3.x

Программа должна 100 раз подбросить монетку и написать сколько орлов и решек выпало, но она не запускается.

```
import random
print ("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t'Орёл-решка'")
print ("\t\nДанная программа 'подбрасывает' монету 100 раз и сообщает...")
print ("...сколько раз выпал орёл, а сколько - решка.")
heads = 0
tails = 0
times = 0
    flip = random.randint(0, 1)
while flip <= 100:
    if flip == 0:
        heads += 1
    if flip == 1:
        tails += 1
    times +=1   
print (heads, tails)
input()
```

Comment: Что именно не работает ?

Comment: У меня не запускается командная строка с этой программой.

Answer (score 3):

несколько ошибок в блоке while. Проверяется  не то, и монетка бросается только один раз. Вот так работает:

```
while times < 100: # условие выхода - количество бросков, а не результат броска монетки
    flip = random.randint(0, 1) # бросаем монетку в цикле
    if flip == 0:
        heads += 1
    if flip == 1:
        tails += 1
    times +=1
```

Еще я изменил условие с `<=` на `<`, потому что с `<=` монетка бросается 101 раз.

Comment: Вне цикла монетка бросится один раз и все. Почему <, а не <= я написал в ответе. Можно оставить <=, но тогда надо изменить на times = 1.

Comment: Хорошо. Получается отсчет начинается с 0, включая сам ноль? И до 99, включая 99?

Comment: Начинается с того числа, которое в начале присваивается переменно и продолжается до тех пор, пока выполняется условие. Когда times = 100, то при <=100 выполняется еще одна итерация, а при <100 - нет, т.к. times уже не меньше 100.